# want to use logical replication with a postgresql10 cluster (that is not using logical replication)

Tags: postgresql-10

We presently have an active/standby postgresql 10 cluster (based on PAF/clusterlabs). Anyways, the servers are kept in sync using:
wal_level = replica

This is fine and working.

However, we would like to replicate a single database from the cluster to a standalone instance (for analytics), for this we figured a logical replication of the single database would do nicely, however we then realized we would need change the replication type on the cluster (which would essentially break it)

wal_level = logical

Is the above assumption correct (cant mix "replica and logical")? Are there any other suggestion on how to achieve the same result (replicating a single database out of the cluster with many databases)

Thanks for any feedback/suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replicating a single database can only be done using logical replication.

You just need to change the `wal_level` from `replica` to `logical`.

The level `logical` includes all the information that `replica` includes, plus some more that's required for logical replication. So changing it, won't break your streaming (physical) replication.

Comment: ah many thanks. after some tests you are absolutely correct.

Comment: Will this configuration of wal_level deteriorate the performance of ordinary DMLs like INSERT and UPDATE?